# Sort an array such a way that First half should be in ascending order Second half should be in descending order in java

Tags: java, sorting

I have searched a lot in google but I didnt get any kind of solution I could use.  Suppose input of array is:

```
 {3,1,2,4,9,8,7,6,5,10}
```

then output must be like this:

```
 {1,2,3,4,5,10,9,8,7,6}
```

by using Basic Java .

Comment: So did you try anything at all?

Comment: well, the simplest solution is to divide the array in two, sort each array, and combine it back into a single array...

Comment: @AmirAfghani Well, that would not really work so smoothly.

Comment: why wouldn't that work?

Comment: @AmirAfghani Will you please post an sample code of it .

Comment: @AmirAfghani Because that's not the homework assignment; look at the before/after.

Comment: How would you divide the array? Just on middle element. If you sort both the array in increasing order, there can be elements in the 2nd array, which is smaller than some in 1st array. Then how would you merge?

Comment: @user3203636 You have homework. That means you should do it, not us.

Comment: ohhh, nevermind you guys are right.  coffee hasn't hit the system yet

Comment: Ok, here's a hint: Sort the array. Reverse the 2nd half. Common, don't really expect us to write out the code.

Comment: @AmirAfghani you just got it in the wrong order. i.e. Sort it, split it, reverse the second half, reassemble it.

Comment: `Arrays.sort(int[] a)` for the whole list, then `Arrays.sort(T[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, Comparator<? super T> c)` for the second half. Sorts everything in-place, no splitting & merging needed. Consult the [`java.util.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) docs for sorting methods.

Comment: What's Basic Java? Does it include the JDK?

Comment: @mdl That doesn't comply with the requirement, which is to sort the entire array and then reverse the second half.

Comment: @RohitJain It's frustrating that `java.util.Arrays` doesn't have `reverse`...

Comment: @user3203636 Good logical question, +1 for the question

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Really. Don't understand why they haven't given a parallel companion to `Collections.reverse()`. Some stuffs in JDK really seems like they really call for improvements.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik My approach does work, but for `Integer` arrays, not `int` (since you can't have a Comparator on a primitive type). So my previous comment should techincally specify `Arrays.sort(Object[] a)` for the first half and `Arrays.sort(Integer[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, Comparator<Integer> c)` for the second half.

Answer (score 4):

- Your array: {3,1,2,4,9,8,7,6,5,10}
- Sort it in ascending order: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
- Break this array into two half arrays:  {1,2,3,4,5}{6,7,8,9,10}
- Sort the second array in descending order or reverse it: {10, 9,8,7,6}
- Add the second array to the first array & you get: {1,2,3,4,5,10,9,8,7,6}

Comment: A bit redundant work here... 1. sort ascending; 2. reverse the second half.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik if the goal of the exercise is to learn sort why not? :P

Comment: @gtgaxiola You get to learn it in step 1. Do you think you'll learn twice as much by calling the sorting function twice?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I have accepted your suggestion and edited my answer accordingly. Thank you

Comment: Actually, I meant without any splitting, which is really uncalled for.

Answer (score 2):

This would be the minimal code which uses an array of *primitive* ints:

```
static final int[] xs = {3,1,2,4,9,8,7,6,5,10};
static void sortAndReverse() {
  Arrays.sort(xs);
  for (int i = xs.length/2; i < dest(i); i++) {
    int tmp = xs[i]; xs[i] = xs[dest(i)]; xs[dest(i)] = tmp;
  }
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xs));
}
static int dest(int i) { return 3*xs.length/2-i-1; }
```

If you're not ashamed of using wrapper objects, then this is unbeatable:

```
final Integer[] xs = {3,1,2,4,9,8,7,6,5,10};
final List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(xs);
Collections.sort(list);
Collections.reverse(list.subList(list.size()/2, list.size()));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xs));
```

Comment: +1 for the portion with the wrapper object & Collections. That looks great!

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below code

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class fre {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] vals = { 3, 1, 2, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 10 };

        Arrays.sort(vals); // Sorts the basic first array
        int[] vals2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(vals, vals.length / 2, vals.length); // Gets the las values of the arrays i.e. it devies the array in multiple same part and another array is created

            // Below loop will reverse the second array
        for (int i = 0; i < vals2.length / 2; i++) {
            int temp = vals2[i];
            vals2[i] = vals2[vals2.length - 1 - i];
            vals2[vals2.length - 1 - i] = temp;
        }

        vals = Arrays.copyOfRange(vals, 0, vals.length / 2);
            // Final array array1and2  will be created where we will append first array with second array
        int[] array1and2 = new int[vals.length + vals2.length];
        System.arraycopy(vals, 0, array1and2, 0, vals.length);
        System.arraycopy(vals2, 0, array1and2, vals.length, vals2.length);
            // Prints the final result array
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1and2));
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6]
```

Comment: Yah, this may be improved but I leave this on OP that he improve the code, I just gave the basic logic for the question

Comment: The basic logic doesn't involve anything more than a single array. I'd say this isn't very didactic.

Comment: @RohitJain This is just my logic which I thought thats it as it can further be improved a lot, I just gave basic idea that how to do this problem solve

Comment: @BhavikAmbani Ok, if you wanted to give a basic idea, you should have at least put some comments there. I don't think OP will be able to understand the logic with that code.

Comment: @RohitJain Yes that can be done. But please appriciate the answer my friend by giving some upvotes :D :D :D

Comment: @BhavikAmbani Lol. Now you have to earn it, by improving it :) Make it really helpful for OP.

Comment: @RohitJain I have updated my answer, please make further comment if you think it is more need to place comments

Answer (score 0):

You can use the java features to do this too ... Use

```
public static <T> void sort(T[] a,
        int fromIndex,
        int toIndex,
        Comparator<? super T> c)
```

But the elements need to be objects ... The comparator needs to be changed while sorting the first half and second half of the array.

Comment: If you go for wrappers, then the prime choice is a two-liner: `Collections.sort(list); Collections.reverse(list.subList(list.size/2, list.size());`

Answer (score 0):

Should be a bit simpler than manually reversing each item in the second half.

```
Integer [] array = { 3,1,2,4,9,8,7,6,5,10 };
Arrays.sort(array);
Arrays.sort(array, array.length/2, array.length, new Comparator<Integer>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2)
    {
        return -o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

---

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6]`

Comment: Wait till you see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder()) :) But really, once you let wrapper objects in, your way is just a slower version of `Collections.sort(); Collections.reverse()`.

Comment: `Collections.reverseOrder()`! Wish I'd known about that one, thanks for the insight. My whole second sort becomes `Arrays.sort(array, array.length/2, array.length, Collections.reverseOrder());`. Good point about the wrappers; really this just highlights how peculiar the lack of `Arrays.reverse(int[] a)` methods are.

Answer (score 0):

IPSOS isn't it?

```
    int m;
    if(array.length%2==0) 
        m=array.length/2;
    else
        m=(array.length+1)/2;

    for(int i=0; i<array.length; ++i){
        if(i<m){
            int min = i;
            for(int j=i+1; j<m;++j){

                if(array[min]>array[j]){
                    min=j;
                }
                int tem = array[i];
                array[i]=array[min];
                array[min]=tem;
            }
        }
        else {
            int max = i;
            for(int k=i+1; k<array.length; ++k){
                if(array[max]<array[k]){
                    max=k;
                }
                int te = array[i];
                array[i]=array[max];
                array[max]=te;
            }
        }           
    }
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;++i){
        System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Sort the array input_Array[] 
2. j = lenght(input_Array)-1
3. loop i = lenght(input_Array)/2 to j
      swap(input_Array[i] , input_Array[j-i])
```

input: 3,1,2,4,9,8,7,6,5,10

output: 1 3 5 7 9 10 8 6 4 2 (uniform acceding and descending )

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class AscendingDecending {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        int a[]= {2,3,2,5,7,5,6,3};
        int i,j,temp;

        //Traverse the element of array
        System.out.println("Input:");
        for(i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("  "+ a[i]);
        }

        //lets move for ascending function
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Output:");

        //Create a Swap Function for sorting
        for(i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            for(j=i+1; j<a.length; j++) {
                if(a[i]>a[j]) {
                    temp= a[i];
                    a[i]= a[j];
                    a[j]= temp;
                }
            }
        }

    // Now the input is in sorted order
    for(i=0; i<a.length/2; i++) {
        System.out.print(" "+ a[i]);
    }

    //For Descending
    for(i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j<a.length; j++) {
            if(a[i]<a[j]) {
                temp= a[i];
                a[i]= a[j];
                a[j]= temp;
            }
        }
    }

// Now the input is in sorted order
System.out.println(" ");
for(i=0; i<a.length/2; i++) {
    System.out.print(" "+ a[i]);
}

}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this piece of code will help:

```
static void printarray(int[] arr, int len)
{
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) 
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    for (int j = len - 1; j >= len / 2; j--)
    System.out.println(arr[j]);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.  In particular, this appears not to sort the second half of the array; it just iterates over it in reverse order.